# MySQL - Call several procedures in one query

Tags: mysql, call, procedure

I have a problem with calling procedure several time in one query. When I call each one separately everything is ok. I do not use MySQL in my everyday work so maybe it is some simple problem :) Thanks for help!

```
CALL DATA_PROCEDURE('text1', 'text2', 1);
CALL DATA_PROCEDURE('text3', 'text4', 2);
CALL DATA_PROCEDURE('text5', 'text6', 3);
CALL DATA_PROCEDURE('text7', 'text8', 4);
```

Comment: How does this problem present ? NB you can't call a procedure from a query..Please add procedure code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try our this code

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_abc()
BEGIN
  CALL sp_a();
  CALL sp_b();
  CALL sp_c();
END$$
DELIMITER
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if calling the same procedure serveral times all in a parent procedure would make much sense in this case, because each procedure uses different IN parameters, so you can't simply repeat the same procedure for a predefined X times.  However, if all those IN parameters have a sequential pattern like the following: 
(textN,textN+1,X) 
(textN+2,textN+3,X+1) 
(textN+4,textN+5,X+2) 
 we may consider using more dynamic approach to accomplish the tedious task:

```
delimiter //
drop procedure if exists repeat_sproc//
create procedure repeat_sproc(counter int unsigned)
begin
declare n int default 1;
declare x int default 1;
lp:loop
if x>counter then
leave lp;
end if;
set @stmt=concat("call DATA_PROCEDURE('text",n,"', 'text",n+1,"',",x,");");
prepare stmt from @stmt;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
set n=n+2;
set x=x+1;
end loop lp; 

end//
delimiter ;
call repeat_sproc(4); -- run the nested procedure four times
```